# Gemspec dependency conflicts

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm writing a gem that depends on another gem X, but X has outdated dependencies that conflict with my gem's dependencies. (specifically, multi_json-1.7.x conflicts with X's multi_json-1.1.x)

Unfortunately X's author is MIA.  Someone else has forked X's repo and has written a fix.

Is there a way to specify this new fork in my `.gemspec`? If not, what are my options for resolving this dependency conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The fork has it's own Github address, and you just specify `:git => ...`

Comment: gemspec's `gem.add_dependency` doesn't take a `:git` option, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: 'Doh. Got confused with a Gemfile versus Gemspec.